# $state.go is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, angularjs-ng-click

I'm doing a web app with AngularJs and I'm using $state to travel into the app. After the login, I want to go to the home *(state 'app.dashboard.home' of the absolute state 'app.dashboard)*.

In this page, there is a button to go in another view called expense *(state 'app.dashboard.expense' of the absolute state 'app.dashboard)*. But when I click on the button, console display this error:

> $state.go is not a function

Why?

This is the routing:

```
angular.module('app')
.run(
['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  }
]
)
 .config(
['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/app/authenticating/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'common/mainApp.html'
    })

    .state('app.auth', {
      url: '/authenticating/',
      templateUrl: 'common/authenticating/authenticating.html',
      controller: 'authenticatingCtrl',
      resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
          function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              files: [
                'common/authenticating/controllers/authenticatingCtrl.js'
              ]
            }).then(function success(args) {
              console.log('success');
              return args;
            }, function error(err) {
              console.log(err);
              return err;
            });
          }]
      }
    })

    .state('app.dashboard', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
      resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
          function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              files: [
                'dashboard/dashboardCtrl.js'
              ]
            }).then(function success(args) {
              console.log('success');
              return args;
            }, function error(err) {
              console.log(err);
              return err;
            });
          }]
      }
    })

    .state('app.dashboard.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'content': {templateUrl: 'dashboard/home/home.html'}
      },
      resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
          function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              files: [
                'dashboard/home/homeCtrl.js'
              ]
            }).then(function success(args) {
              console.log('success');
              return args;
            }, function error(err) {
              console.log(err);
              return err;
            });
          }]
      }
    })

      .state('app.dashboard.expense', {
        url: '/newExpenseList',
        views: {
          'content': {templateUrl: 'dashboard/expense/new/new.html'}
        },
        resolve: {
          deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
            function($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                files: [
                  'dashboard/expense/new/newCtrl.js'
                ]
              }).then(function success(args) {
                console.log('success');
                return args;
              }, function error(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return err;
              });
            }]
        }
      })

}])
```

This is the dashboard.html:

```
<div class="content-wrap" nav-collapse-toggler type="swipe">
     <main role="main" >
         <div class="section-info">
             <div class="section-subtitle">{{app.name}}</div>
         </div>
          <div id="content" class="content view-animate fade-up" ui-view="content"></div>
     </main>
</div>
```

This is the homeCtrl:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'toaster', 'GlobalApplicationData', '$log', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($http, $scope, $rootScope, GlobalApplicationData, $log, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.goToNewExpenseList = function() {
        $state.go('app.dashboard.expense');
        };
    }]);
```

This is the home.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div class="form">
            <button class="lol" ng-click="goToNewExpenseList()">Go to expense list</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in a wrong parameter array *definition*, and *declared function parameters*.

The forth is declared **`'toaster'`**, but that is missing in function params... so all others are shifted and contain different stuff

```
['$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'toaster', 'GlobalApplicationData', '$log', '$state', '$stateParams',
// original is missing 4th param
//function($http, $scope, $rootScope, GlobalApplicationData, $log, $state, $stateParams) 
// here we get $state as $state, because the 4th param will be toaster
function($http, $scope, $rootScope, toaster, GlobalApplicationData, $log, $state,  $stateParams)
```

Comment: My God, how did I not realize. Thank you so much, when the timeout ends I accept the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Great to see that ;) Those issues are pain... ;)